# Display elements based on instantaneous change and full or empty input on vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple form that has a **search-bar** and **two buttons**. I want the fill button to be displayed if there is a value in the input and only the empty button to be displayed if there is no value in the input.
I want to affect the display or non-display of the buttons instantly and with any change, whether the input is full or empty. How is this handled in Vue js?

The scenario is that in fact the fill button is displayed when the input has a value, and by pressing it, the input is empty and reset, and as a result, the button itself is non-display and the empty button is displayed. The fill button is to empty the input when it has any value.

```
<form class="myform">

  <button type="reset" class="fill">Show when fill </button>
  
  <button class="empty">Show when empty</button>

  <input type="search" class="myinput">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should help.

```
   <template>
      <div id="app">
       <form class="myform">
    
          <button @click.prevent="reset" v-if="search" type="reset" class="fill">Show when fill 
          </button>
          
          <button v-else  class="empty">Show when empty</button>
    
          <input v-model="search" type="search" class="myinput">
    
        </form>
      </div>
    </template>
   <script>
    export default {
      name: "App",
      data() {
        return {
          search: null,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        reset() {
          thid.search = null;
        }
      }

    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Using the model does not help because after clearing the value inside the input via the reset button, the previous value will still remain in the model variable and while the input is empty but the previous value still remains in the model variable, maybe use the watch Can be a way forward.

Comment: You may have to use event listener and reset model yourself.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11175 Found this issue already logged. I have updated the example code as well

Comment: Do you think that by using the watch and monitoring the changes with @change in the input, can the value of the variable be connected to the value inside the input?
For example, by checking whether the length of the value inside the input is greater than zero with each change or not, can the watch property be used with ref attr to input ?

Comment: I don't think it will help. type reset does not trigger any change. it could be directly modifying actual dom instead of vue's shadow dom. I am not 100% sure about this but this is my guess